# How to prevent default link behavior if element inside of link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="page.html" class="myLink">
  Link text
  <div class="toggle">x</div>
</a>
```

When they click on the `x` in toggle I want to prevent the link from navigating, but if they do click on the `Link Text` I want the link to navigate.

I tried this:

`$('.toggle').click(function(event) { $(this).parents('a').preventDefault(); });`

But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ will tell you it's a method of the event object, not the jQuery object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To stop propagation from the clicked element to the outer `a`, you'd have to call [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). But here you can simply return false ( which both stops propagation and prevents default behavior) :

```
$('.toggle').click(function(event) {
    // do interesting things   
    return false
});
```

Comment: Notably, this doesn't seem to work if there's a listener on the `mouseup` event even if there's a listener that stops propagation for all three of the `mousedown` and `click` and `mouseup` events. It works without issue for `mousedown` events.

Answer (score 2):

It is the event not the element that you need to fire the preventDefault() method upon.

```
$('.toggle').click(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

This will stop the event from triggering but not propagating up the document.

```
$('.toggle').click(function (event) { 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Is it's counterpart.